# activemq trusted package Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am running my broker but when I am pulling the message from queue getting following  exception.

```
Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class demo.CollectorProcessInfo! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

tried the solution given in folloing link.
[SpringBoot + ActiveMQ - How to set trusted packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619432/springboot-activemq-how-to-set-trusted-packages)

also tried  **-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=***

but not help.

Here is the code to pull the message

```
public QueueMessage pull(QUEUENAME queueName,
        long timeOutInMilliSeconds) throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    try{
        ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory();
        connection = factory.getConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue(queueName.toString());
        consumer = session
                .createConsumer(destination);
        ObjectMessage receivedMessage = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive(timeOutInMilliSeconds);
        QueueMessage message = null;
        if(receivedMessage != null){
            message = (QueueMessage) receivedMessage.getObject();
        }
        else{
            logger.debug("Received message is null on a timeout");
        }
        return message;
    }
    finally{
        if(consumer!=null)
            consumer.close();
        if(session!=null)
            session.close();
        if(connection!=null)
            connection.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: please give more info how are pulling message and converting to your object

Comment: @HakobHakobyan , I have updated my question

Comment: @HakobHakobyan, My spring boot application is not doing anything with activemq broker, boot application have dependency on other project which is starting it internal broker and queuing the messages and pulling from queue

Comment: I just add the dependecy of that project